# Remove certain characters of array variable?

Tags: php, arrays, bigcommerce

I would like to remove the last certain characters of following array api variable 'min_date_created' like

```
$filter = array('min_date_created' => "$start_date");//query filter
```

Here the values of

```
'min_date_created'=Mon, 24 Sep 2012 00:53:26 +0000
```

So i want to remove the last 15 characters, so i expect the following format

```
'min_date_created'=Mon, 24 Sep 2012
```

So please any one help me how can i change this array variable 'min_date_created' in required format.

Answer (score 1):

You can format using the date & strtotime function like below

https://www.php.net/strtotime

```
<?php 

  //format the date
 $min_date_created = date('D, d M Y', strtotime($start_date));

 $filter =  array('min_date_created'=>$min_date_created);
```

Comment: Thanking you. But here i don't want to change the value of variable $start_date .Just i want to removed the last 15 digits of array variable 'min_date_created' only. So i would like to expect some array functions like substr etc.

Comment: $start_date is different variable that will never change

Answer (score 1):

Expanding [`Sundar's Answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21981197/1003917) , You can achieve simpler using an `array_walk` to do modify all the array elements in a single go.

```
<?php
$startdate="Mon, 24 Sep 2012 00:53:26 +0000"; // Usually you will be getting from a POST variable.
$filter = array('min_date_created' => $startdate);
array_walk($filter,'formatDT');
function formatDT(&$v,$k)
{
    $v=date('D, d M Y', strtotime($v));
}
print_r($filter);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [min_date_created] => Mon, 24 Sep 2012
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **substr** to remove the last 15 characters from $start_date before using it in the array.

```
$filter = array('min_date_created' => substr($start_date, 0, -15));
```

*Output*

```
array (
    'min_date_created' => 'Mon, 24 Sep 2012',
)
```